# C++ vs MEX timing difference

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, mex, armadillo

I have a mex(MATLAB version of C++) function that I want to convert to C++. It's very similar except for the main() function. But one of the sub-functions is running considerably slower when compiled with C++ vs mex.

I compile my mex code via:

`mex -v COMPFLAGS='$COMPFLAGS /std:c++11' COPTIMFLAGS="-O3" CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fopenmp" rcp_adp.cpp -I/usr/include ini.c -I/usr/include cpp/INIReader.cpp -larmadillo -lopenblas -lgomp -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm -lpthread`

and I use this for C++ compile:

`g++ --verbose -std=c++11 rcp_main.cpp -I/usr/include ini.c -I/usr/include cpp/INIReader.cpp -O3 -larmadillo -llapack -lopenblas -lgomp -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm -fopenmp -lpthread`

I cannot post the sub-function but it is using armadillo functions and a parallel for loop for signal processing. The timing difference goes from 0.5sec to 25sec.

The for loops are called like so:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(max_threads) /*do processing in parallel threads*/
    for(int ii=0;ii<Nsp;ii++){
    }
```

I'm at a loss for what could be causing the timing difference. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I just wanted to clarify, this is the exact code running in both instances. Its a header file written in C++. The only difference is that one version is compile inside MATLAB using the mex command, that is linked with g++ while the other version is just with g++.

So my working theory is that when using MEX/G++/MATLAB to compile, MATLAB is forcing the compiler to use MATLABs versions of LAPACK and BLAS vs the linked openblas and lapack.I plan on testing this tomorrow afternoon with a simplified version of the code and while update with results.

EDIT:
Sorry, forgot to mention I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I haven't run my test yet, but I have looked further into openblas. I see that there is openblas-openmp, how can I link to that instead of the standard openblas?

Comment: Answering performance questions without any code is pure speculation.  For example, MATLAB is known to highly optimize their math functions; they may be more efficient than the C++ standard library functions.

Comment: I highly recommend running a profiler on your code, which should give you a characterization of where the time is spent in your program.  Try optimizing those sections.  Remember, 80% of the execution time is in 20% of the code (or something like that).

Comment: As long as we are speculating, it could be parallelization issue. Without knowing anything else about what code you are running (ahem!), it could be that Matlab (which is a single threaded application) does not enjoy the same speedups from doing things in parallel as does your executable compiled with gcc.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the `CFLAGS` environment variable is not used. You are not passing the `-fopenmp` flag to the compiler. I am also not sure about the `COPTIMFLAGS` flag, you might not be passing the `-O3` flag either.

On Windows, use the `COMPFLAGS` environment variable to pass flags to the compiler. On Linux and macOS, use `CFLAGS` for the C compiler and `CXXFLAGS` for the C++ compiler. This is described [here in the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#btw193g-1).

If you run `mex` from within MATLAB, do

```matlab
mex -v COMPFLAGS='$COMPFLAGS -std=c++11 -O3 -fopenmp' rcp_adp.cpp -I/usr/include ini.c -I/usr/include cpp/INIReader.cpp -larmadillo -lopenblas -lgomp -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lm -lpthread
```

If you run `mex` from the Windows command prompt, use `"` instead of `'`.

Answer (score 0):

So fixed the issue. It seems like MEX/MATLAB was compiling with mkl blas libraries while g++ was compiling with standard openblas. I install openblas-openmp

```
sudo apt install libopenblas-openmp-dev
```

then I updated where link was point to, so that it pointed to the openmp version (repeat for lapack):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config libopenblas.so.0-x86_64-linux-gnu
```

And the timing discrepancies disappeared.